# Serialize/Deserialize an ArrayList

Tags: java, serialization, arraylist

i'm building a Java project and I need to serialize and deserialize an ArrayList of items, I cant' do it with the arraylist but i have to do it with each element of the ArrayList. Somehow, i managed to serialize it, but whenever i try to deserialize it i get this :
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Here's the code :

```
    File f = new File("testo2.txt");
    int i = 0;
    ArrayList<DispositivoSelezioneProgrammi> list = new ArrayList<DispositivoSelezioneProgrammi>();
    if(f.exists())
    {
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));

        while(in.read() != -1)
        {
            list.add((DispositivoSelezioneProgrammi)in.readObject());

        }
    }
    else
    {

        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f));
        Programma prog1 = new Programma("Lana");
        Programma prog2 = new Programma("Seta");
        Programma prog3 = new Programma("Rapido");
        ArrayList<Programma> lista = new ArrayList<Programma>();
        lista.add(0,prog1);
        lista.add(1,prog2);
        lista.add(2,prog3);
        Lavatrice lav1 = new Lavatrice("Asd","lol",lista);
        Lavatrice lav2 = new Lavatrice("Fgh","kok",lista);
        Lavatrice lav3 = new Lavatrice("Jkl","pop",lista);

        Canzone canz1 = new Canzone("Bella");
        Canzone canz2 = new Canzone("Brutta");
        Canzone canz3 = new Canzone("Qwerty");
        ArrayList<Canzone> canz = new ArrayList<Canzone>();
        canz.add(0,canz1);
        canz.add(1,canz2);
        canz.add(2,canz3);
        LettoreMP3 lett1 = new LettoreMP3("Lett1");
        lett1.load(canz);
        LettoreMP3 lett2 = new LettoreMP3("Lett2");
        lett2.load(canz);
        LettoreMP3 lett3 = new LettoreMP3("Lett3");
        lett3.load(canz);

        list.add(0,lav1);
        list.add(1,lav2);
        list.add(2,lav3);
        list.add(3,lett1);
        list.add(4,lett2);
        list.add(5,lett3);
        for(DispositivoSelezioneProgrammi disp : list)
        {               
            out.writeObject(disp);
        }
        out.close();
    }
```

Could you please help me? I don't understand what happens!
I almost forgot, Lavatrice and LettoreMP3 implements the DispositvoSelezioneProgrammi interface, that's why I use it as a super type to serialize them!

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList is Serializable, you should write/read it directly

Answer (score 0):

When deserializing you have created an empty ArrayList `list`. You must not try to add elements with `list.set(i, ...); i++;`! Instead use `list.add(...)`.
See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html for details.

Answer (score 0):

you are using the wrong signal indicator for detecting if the stream has data to be read from.Use -1 instead of 1 on the while statement

Comment: Now i fixed it, up there is the new code. Now i have another problem, if the file doesn't exist it works properly, and serialize data, but if the file exists it doesn't do anything, and terminate without errors but without showing anything!